# Android Flip vertical animation xml

Tags: android, android-animation

i want to create Flip vertical animation in my application but all of my found document are flip horizontal and i can not find any document about flip vertical by xml or java class
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by putting two views of the same size one below the other and use the ViewPropertyAnimator like this:

```
firstView.animate().rotationX(90).setDuration(200).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    firstView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    secondView.setRotationX(-90);
                    secondView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    secondView.animate().rotationX(0).setDuration(200).setListener(null);
                }
            });
```

The first view is visible when starts, and the second one, obviously it's invisible.